# What happens when minSdkVersion changes in an app update?

Tags: android, google-play

When i publish an update that change minSdkVersion from 8 to 16 for example: what happens to api 8 users that have already downloaded my app?

Comment: Thank, good answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can't install the update and will be using the old version till the end. Depending on the app store you're using they most likely won't even know, that there was an update.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the API , some work, some do not make your application does not work. Investigate compatibility libraries

Comment: Sorry, i meaned "minSdkVersion"